# Is there a shortcut to insert # at the beginning of a block of code?

Tags: notepad++

I'm currently using the **Alt** key to insert several **#** in front of lines of code that I want to temporarily turn off in my python script.

Is there a shortcut or a way to select a block of code and turning it on/off faster in Notepad ++?

Answer (score 1):

Select your block, then "CTRL + Q".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome ! Mark it as solved would be nice :)